# Rigorously Proving Countable Additivity of Discrete Measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm trying to show, in full rigor, that a measure on a discrete probability space is necessarily countably additive. That is, with countable $\Omega$ and $p: \sum_{x\in \Omega} p(x) = 1$ and $p(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$, we define:

$P(A) = \sum_{x\in A} p(x)$

Now my hand-wavy solution is, with the $A_i$ disjoint:

$P(\bigcup A_i) =\sum_{x\in \bigcup A_i} p(x) = \sum_i \sum_{x\in A_i} p(x) = \sum_i P(A_i) $

But it feels like the middle equality is doing some work that I can't necessarily justify. Specifically, if the collection of $i$ is countably infinite, and each $A_i$ is countably infinite.

Comment: the justification is based on well known Calculus result about rearrangements of absolutely convergent series (in the present case convergent series with nonnegative terms). This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/676122/121671) addresses rearrangements of absolutely convergent series. Other related results are about regrouping elements of convergent series in blocks.

Comment: I can't immediately see how to extend that to the case of an infinite series of infinite series. I can rearrange the terms, but I don't see a way to rearrange them so as to generate the statement above

Comment: T. Apostol's Mathematical analysis book has a nice section on series where rearrangement and regroupings are studied.

Comment: Practically speaking, your proof does not need any more justification. Generally any proof in math has to stop at some level of obviousness which doesn't need more proof. Since the exercise is from measure theory, you should be allowed to use any necessary fact from analysis.

However, if you want to go deeper and prove the problematic fact rigorously (warning - it will be arduous), the first step is to rigorously define a sum over a countable set, i.e. what exactly is $\sum_{x \in A} f(x)$ for a countable set $A$ and function $f : A \to [0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What make things work are some basic properties of absolutely convergent series (in the present case, it suffices to consider convergent series with nonnegative terms) and combinations of such properties:

1. *adding and removing parenthesis*,

> Theorem 1. Let $p:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be a strictly monotone increasing function. Given a series $\sum_na_n$ define
> $$\begin{align}
> b_1&=a_1+\ldots + a_{p(1)},\\
> b_n&=a_{p(n)+1}+\ldots a_{p(n+1)}
> \end{align}$$
> ans consider the series $\sum_nb_n$. If $\sum_na_n$ converges to $s$, then $\sum_nb_n$ also converges to $s$.

2. *rearrangements*,

> Theorem: Suppose $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is a bijective function. For any series $\sum_na_n$ define $b_n=a_{f(n)}$ and consider the series $\sum_nb_n$. If the series $\sum_na_n$ converges absolutely and $\sum_na_n=s$, then $\sum_nb_n$ also converges absolutely and $\sum_nb_n=s$.

3. *forming subsequences*,

> Theorem: Suppose $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is injective. For any series $\sum_na_n$ define $b_n=a_{f(n)}$. Is $\sum_na_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum_nb_n$ converges absolutely.

4. *partitioning or subgrouping series*.

> Theorem: Suppose $\{f_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a sequence of injective functions from $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\{f_k(\mathbb{N}):k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ forms a partition of $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e. the sets $f_n(\mathbb{N})$ are pairwise disjoint and their union is $\mathbb{N}$). Given a series $\sum_na_n$ define
> $b_k(n)=a_{f_k(n)}$, and
> $$s_k=\sum_nb_k(n)$$
> If $\sum_na_n$ is absolutely convergent and $\sum_na_n=s$, then  the series $\sum_ks_k$ is also absolutely convergent, and $\sum_ks_k=s$.

I omit proofs  of these results as they can be found in many Calculus and Analysis textbooks that cover convergence of series. A nice reference is *Apostol, T. Mathematical Analysis, 2nd edition,  Addison Wesley,  1974* pp. 187, 196-199.

Comment: Excellent, theorem 4 was exactly what I was looking for. It seems intuitively true, but I hadn't seen a formal statement as such

Comment: How to use Theorem $4$  ,for finite $A_{i}'s$ ? I mean in that case we dont have injective function .

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. If subadditivity is what you want to check, the one can decompose the sets $A_j$ into disjoint sets: $B_1=A_1$, $B_j=A_j\setminus\bigcup^{j-1}_{k=1}B_k$. Then $\bigcup_nB_n=\bigcup_nA_n$ and additivity can be applied to $\{B_n\}$.